# Can gems be gifted across platforms?

Tags: dragonvale

A friend of mine recently got an Android phone, and a few updates back DragonVale was released on Android.  I'm a long time player on the iOS platform, but I'm wondering if there is a way for us to gift gems to one another given DragonVale's cross platform support.  Can gems be gifted to friends across Android, iOS, and Facebook - or can you only gift gems to friends on your platform of choice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, gems can be gifted cross platform. However, because the Android version is not connected to iOS's GameCenter at all, your friend on Android **must be friends with you on Facebook** in order to be able to gift you gems and vice versa. Facebook is the only bridge between the two platforms. I use the Android version and I have 2 friends on iOS and one friend on Android and I have no issues gifting to them.

As a side note, the Android friending is a little buggy still. It took some time before my friends showed up after adding them through Facebook, and Dragonvale will still, on occasion, say that my Friends list is completely empty and/or have specific friends not show up on it randomly. Restarting the app will sometimes fix it, but it occasionally takes more time to fix itself. If this happens, don't worry about messing with Facebook or anything, your friends have not been lost, it's just the app being buggy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @FAE.  At least local to GameCenter that buggy behavior has been explained by your friends and/or you loading an update.  If you are not on the same version, sometimes your friends will not appear (at least temporarily).  I have observed this to be the case empirically.

Comment: @EBongo Good to know! I'm not sure that's the case though given the frequency that it occurs on the Android version. Usually at least once a day (I check this app uh, a lot...), I'll load up the game and have an empty friends list. At this point, I'm just resigned to it happening and try to remember to gift gems later on.

Comment: I was added on Facebook by an iOS friend, and he gifted me a gem, but I couldn't see him until I'd restarted the app, for what it's worth.  Most of the game's tech support appears to boil down to "well, quit the app, and if that doesn't work, reinstall"